# Calculating the series expansion of a theta function

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion, products

I have defined the q-theta function as follows:

$$\theta(x;q) = \prod_{k=0}^{\infty} (1-q^k x)(1-q^{k+1}/x)$$

I want to calculating, using this, the series expansion of the following series:

$$\frac{\theta^2(x)\theta(q^{1/2}x^2)}{\theta^2(a)\theta(ax)\theta(a/x)}$$

As a naive approach, I have defined the theta function as the above product in my Mathematica file and tried a series expansion of the more complicated function using Series, about {z,0,2}, say, but unfortunately my code doesn't return anything useful and/or accurate. Instead I get a mess of Pochhammer symbols which I think are incorrect.

If anyone has any tips on calculating the series expansions of these types of q-hypergeometric function-related objects,I would be extremely grateful.

```
θ[z_, q_] := Product[(1 - q^k z) (1 - q^(k + 1)/z), {k, 0, ∞}];
Series[(θ[x, q]/θ[a, q])^2 θ[q^(1/2) x^2, q]/(θ[a*x, q] θ[a/x, q]), {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Could you include what you have tried?

Comment: Added my input attempt

Comment: Could you consider taking the logarithm and doing an expansion of that?

Comment: I have tried that, but I keep getting QPochhamer[f[x],q] factors (where f[x] is a function of x, such as 1/x or q/(ax), they appear in various places) when I want a series expansion in x itself.

Comment: Not all series expansions in `x` are polynomials in `x`, e.g., `Series[a x^(1/2) + b Gamma[x] + c x + d x^2, {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Duplication of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316342/laurent-series-expansion-of-theta-function-expression

Comment: Why don't you use `EllipticTheta[]`?

Comment: Sorry:) Why don't you use `QPochhammer[]`?

Comment: The problem is QPochhammer[f[x],q] symbols appearing in the denominator, indicating a failure in the expansion. I have tried EllipticTheta etc., but I know that it is possible to write down a good Laurent expansion when the numerator has \theta(x^2) term instead of a \theta(q^{1/2}x^2) term, and I would like to compare with that. My main issue is computing a bona fide series expansion in powers of x for this object that is defined as an infinite product.

Comment: Are you sure that the series expansion is even well-defined?  Graphing the functions for various values of $q$ (`Table[Plot[Evaluate[T[x, q]], {x, -0.1, 0.1}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], {q, -1/2, 1/2, 1/4}]`, using [Somos's code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186846/27813)), I see the sort of rapid oscillation at $x = 0$ that I always associate with an essential singularity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code with an example:

```
QP[a_, q_] := QPochhammer[a, q];
(* T[x, q] == Product[(1 - x q^k) (1 - q/x q^k), {k, 0, Infinity}] *)
T[x_, q_] := QP[x, q] QP[q/x, q];
U[a_, x_, Q_] := With[{q = Q^2}, (T[x, q]^2 T[Q x^2 , q]) /
             (T[a, q]^2 T[a x, q] T[a/x, q])];
A = U[q^2, q^1, q^5] + O[q]^11
```

You will get an ordinary power series in q.

However, you wanted a series in x instead. Try something like this:

```
(List @@ Normal[ U[a, x, q] + O[q]^6)(1 + O[x]^4) // Total // Simplify
```

With various series truncations. You will get truncations of a series in powers of x and 1/x.

Try this:

```
L[a_, x_, Q_, n_] := Normal[U[a, x, Q] + O[Q]^n] + x O[x]^Quotient[n + 1, 2] // Expand;
L[x^2, x, q, 5]
```

in order o get a truncation of the series in x. To compare to the q-series, try this:

```
Do[Print[n, ": ", (Normal[L[q^2, q^1, Q, n]] /. Q -> q^5 ) - A], {n, 10}];
```

in order to see the convergence to the example.

Just to be clear, because of the negative powers of x, we have a Laurent series in x instead of an ordinary power series. This is most likely why you were not able to get a power series in x using the obvious method -- unlike the easy way to get a power series in q.

Answer (score 1):

We use the famous expression  q-theta function $\theta (x;q)=(x;q)_{\infty} (q/x;q)_{\infty}$ where $(x;q)_{\infty}$ is the q-Pochhammer symbol. At `x=0` it is impossible to expand into a `Series`, but you can, for example, expand around `x=1`

```
T0 = QPochhammer[x, q]*QPochhammer[q/x, q];
T1 = QPochhammer[q^(1/2)*x^2, q]*QPochhammer[q/(q^(1/2)*x^2), q];
T2 = QPochhammer[a, q]*QPochhammer[q/a, q];
T3 = QPochhammer[a*x, q]*QPochhammer[q/(a*x), q];
T4 = QPochhammer[a/x, q]*QPochhammer[q/(a/x), q];

S = T0^2*T1/(T2^2*T3*T4);
Series[S, {x, 1, 2}];
Normal[%]


 (*(QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[Sqrt[q], q]^2 QPochhammer[q, q]^2)/(
 QPochhammer[a, q]^4 QPochhammer[q/a, 
   q]^4) - (2 (-1 + x) QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[q, 
     q]^2 (QPochhammer[Sqrt[q], q]^2 QPolyGamma[0, 0, q] - 
      QPochhammer[Sqrt[q], q]^2 QPolyGamma[0, 1, q]))/(Log[
     q] QPochhammer[a, q]^4 QPochhammer[q/a, 
     q]^4) + ((-1 + x)^2 QPochhammer[Sqrt[q], 
     q]^2 (Log[q] QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[q, q]^2 QPolyGamma[
        0, 0, q] + 
      2 QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[q, q]^2 QPolyGamma[0, 0, 
        q]^2 - Log[q] QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[q, 
        q]^2 QPolyGamma[0, 1, q] - 
      4 QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[q, q]^2 QPolyGamma[0, 0, 
        q] QPolyGamma[0, 1, q] + 
      2 QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[q, q]^2 QPolyGamma[0, 1, 
        q]^2 - QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[q, q]^2 QPolyGamma[1, 
        0, q] - QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[q, q]^2 QPolyGamma[1, 
        1, q] + QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[q, q]^2 QPolyGamma[1, 
        Log[a]/Log[q], q] - 
      4 QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[q, q]^2 QPolyGamma[1, 
        Log[Sqrt[q]]/Log[q], q] + 
      QPochhammer[1, q]^2 QPochhammer[q, q]^2 QPolyGamma[1, Log[q/a]/
        Log[q], q]))/(Log[q]^2 QPochhammer[a, q]^4 QPochhammer[q/a, 
     q]^4)*)
```